# MySQL: How to prevent filesort with index for column used in ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a MySQL database for a query that is currently VERY slow:

```
SELECT  Listing.*,  PrimaryPhoto.* 
 FROM listings AS Listing  
 LEFT JOIN file_storage AS PrimaryPhoto  
 ON (PrimaryPhoto.foreign_key  =  Listing.ID  
 AND  PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto') 
 WHERE  Listing.rent  >= 0 
 AND  Listing.rent  <= 5000 
 AND  Listing.beds  >= 1 
 AND  Listing.is_active  = '1' 
 ORDER BY Listing.modified  DESC
```

I've added several indexes to the `listings` table...
[image]
...and here are the indexes for the `file_storage` table...
[image]
...but it is still VERY slow! Like 20+ seconds to run.

The `EXPLAIN` shows me that `filesort` is being used:
[image]

I thought I could prevent `filesort` by adding an index for all 4 columns mentioned in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause. But it hasn't worked.

Did I do something wrong? Or maybe I am looking in the wrong place to speed up this query.

**Update**
Here is the schema for the two tables:

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of user who owns this listing',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Street address (w/o postal code)',
  `lat` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `rent` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Monthly rental price in CAD',
  `lease_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '# of months of lease',
  `date_available` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Day the listing is available',
  `neighborhood_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beds` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '# of bedrooms',
  `baths` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '# of bathrooms',
  `sq_ft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '# of square footage',
  `fridge` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `stove` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `dishwasher` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ac` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `furnished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `laundry` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `balcony` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `patio` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `yard` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pool` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `doorman` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `security` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gym` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `parking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `wheelchair` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `inc_heat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'does the rent include heat?',
  `inc_water` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'doest the rent include water?',
  `inc_internet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'does the rent include internet?',
  `inc_cable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'does the rent include cable?',
  `cats` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'are cats allowed?',
  `small_dogs` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'are small dogs allowed?',
  `big_dogs` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'are big dogs allowed?',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'is the listing active?',
  `is_hot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'hot list',
  `source_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `is_active` (`is_active`),
  KEY `rent` (`rent`),
  KEY `rent_beds_is_active` (`rent`,`beds`,`is_active`),
  KEY `modified` (`modified`),
  KEY `rent_beds_active_modified` (`rent`,`beds`,`is_active`,`modified`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3012 ; ``

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `file_storage` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `foreign_key` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `filesize` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `adapter` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gaufrette Storage Adapter Class',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `foreign_key` (`foreign_key`),
  KEY `model_foreign_key` (`model`,`foreign_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; ``

Comment: How many results does this query produce?

Comment: @eggyal In production this will currently return 975 results

Comment: I see that in your `file_storage` table you have a composite index (model, foreign_key). Try to add a index on `model` only.

Comment: @Daan I added an index for just `model` but it didn't seem to do much. The cardinality was 20.

Comment: How much columns and records do both table have? Can you post the tables?

Comment: @Daan `listings` has 2900 records and 43 columns (~20 of the columns are `TINYINT`s). The `file_storage` table has 20,900 records and 13 columns.

Comment: Do you need all 56 columns in your query? It can make a difference if you just select the columns needed.

Comment: I could omit some of them. Are there some that are more important to exclude than others?

Comment: You could add a multi-column index on `listings(is_active, modified)` to avoid the filesort, but that doesn't necessarily mean it will improve your query too much. There's a lot going on here, and you've not even shown your schema.

Comment: Is PrimaryPhoto.model a varchar type? Make it in integer and create a new table with Models(model_id, model). In general it's not a good idea to create indexes on varchars, edit:  `model varchar(64)` will massivly slow down your query.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I updated the question with the schema for both tables. Are you suggesting I add the index for `is_active` and `modified`? Shouldn't I be working to avoiding `filesort`?

Comment: @Daan I have limited flexibility to hack structure of that table because it's for a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Daan If I can't change the `file_storage` table schema, should I remove the index on the `model` column?

Comment: @SDP Yes the one I recommended to you and also the composite index. Remove the ON clause with `PrimaryPhoto.model` and add it to the `WHERE` clause `PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto'` I've answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT  Listing.*,  PrimaryPhoto.* 
FROM listings AS Listing LEFT JOIN
     file_storage AS PrimaryPhoto  
     ON PrimaryPhoto.foreign_key  =  Listing.ID  AND 
        PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto'
WHERE Listing.rent >= 0 AND  Listing.rent  <= 5000 AND
      Listing.beds  >= 1 AND
      Listing.is_active  = '1' 
ORDER BY Listing.modified  DESC
```

Try this composite index (the order of the keys is important):  `Listing(beds, is_active, modified, rent)`.  A full index on the `where` (that is, `beds, is_active, rent)` will not help with the `order by`.  This one may.  Also, you want an index on `file_storage(foreign_key, model)`.

Comment: Did you see my comment on Daan's answer above? Curious if this interacts with your recommendation at all.

Comment: Moving `PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto'` to the `where` clause changes the `join` to an inner join.  That is a different query.

Comment: Thanks! How did you determine that order of the index columns?

Comment: @SDP . . . Start with the equality conditions in the `where`.  Then, choose an inequality from the `where` or the `order by`.  If the latter, keep your fingers crossed that it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Remove indexes on PrimaryPhoto.model and remove the join add it to the where clause. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT  Listing.*,  PrimaryPhoto.* 
 FROM listings AS Listing  
 LEFT JOIN file_storage AS PrimaryPhoto  
 ON PrimaryPhoto.foreign_key  =  Listing.ID
 WHERE  Listing.rent  >= 0 
 AND  Listing.rent  <= 5000 
 AND  Listing.beds  >= 1 
 AND  Listing.is_active  = '1' 
 AND  PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto'
 ORDER BY Listing.modified  DESC
```

Also try not to make a select with `*` only select the necessary columns.

Comment: Interesting. Could you say a few words explaining the goal of moving the `ON` condition into the `WHERE`? This query is generated by a framework (CakePHP) so understanding the higher purpose will help me whilst I finagle it into doing what I want.

Comment: When you do it within the JOIN, the planner will probably have to select from the table, filter by the "True" part, then join the result sets.A lot of data to look through, and it can't use the indexes as efficiently.

If you do it in a WHERE clause, the planner is choosing a route that is more efficient (ie.  pre filtered dataset). (the index in this story being PrimaryPhoto.foreign_key)

Comment: I'm still researching if there's a way to customize the `ON` condition using CakePHP. But in the mean time I preemptively added the `PrimaryPhoto.model  = 'PrimaryListingPhoto'` to the `WHERE` clause and it seems to help a lot! Is MySQL smart enough to use the WHERE instead of the ON while they are both present? Do you have any other thoughts on why it might already be working (before removing the problematic `ON`)?